# How can I display my Instagram backup data in a friendly way using node js?

Tags: json, view, backup, instagram, datareader

recently i have downloaded a backup of my Instagram account ...

and the zip file contained a lot of ".json" files and i have no idea how to view it like the way Instagram did or something like a Instagram Backup Manager ... i think that it mostly can be done using node js as it's json friendly.

[the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm8iv.png)

thanks

Comment: You can simply do this using this node js based tool 
https://github.com/mainigautam/instagram_backup_manager

or using this online site 

http://backupreader.com/instagram-backup

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to view JSON (from the Instagram backup) is to convert it to CSV.

You can upload the zip file to this [JSON to CSV converter](https://json-csv.com) and it will automatically convert everything into individual CSV files (then you can view / analyze / format the data in Excel).

Here is a [more detailed guide](https://json-csv.com/instagram-export).

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. However could you possibly include some key steps from the guide within your answer itself? The reason is that external links can change, and if the link breaks then your answer becomes less useful.

Comment: Whoa that seems great did you just make this specifically for the question ? Can i upload just messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Any Text Editor will be able to open a JSON file.

Since you want to view it in a friendly way you might want to try [this website](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) or any other json viewer.

Alternatively you can use the built-in Javascript console of Chrome or Firefox (other browsers might work, but I do not know for sure) and just paste the JSON file into there. This will give you the option to explore the loaded object.

Comment: It works .. But it's not friendly at all. ... It needs to keep clicking again and again to be able to see just one message ..

Comment: JSON files are only made to store data. To show this data in the specific format you want, you will likely need to make your own program, that takes care of the graphical user interface.

Comment: oh... that's  bad ..... i found that JSON  to csv does it better ....
if you found any thing better please ... notice me and update the answer

.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [**koia.io**](https://www.koia.io/intro/index.html).

Koia is an open-source web application for visualizing and analyzing table-like data structures read from local files (CSV, JSON and Excel). When the data is loaded, it never  leaves your computer but is stored locally only.

Data can be easily filtered and the result can be  stored again to CSV, JSON or Excel files.